# Xamarin forms accessibility order

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, accessibility

I want to change the order VoiceOver and Talkback read the elements in a view. I found that `TabIndex` should set the focus order of the elements in a page so I tried to build a simple example application setting different TabIndex in the order I want but it seems to work only with certains elements (like label, buttons...). I created a random element like a red BoxView and set that as an accessible element `box2.SetValue(AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTreeProperty, true);` but it always receive the focus as the last item, don't know why.
Than I would like to do something to change the accessibility order later in code after something append.
Any suggestion?

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="AccessibilityFocus.MainPage">
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="container">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label x:Name="label1" Text="Label 1" TabIndex="10"/>
        <BoxView x:Name="box2" BackgroundColor="Red" TabIndex="20"/>
        <Label x:Name="label3" Text="Label 3" TabIndex="30"/>

        <Button x:Name="buttonChange"
                Text="CHANGE"
                Clicked="changeFocus"
                TabIndex="40"/>

    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Internals;

namespace AccessibilityFocus
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]


    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        IList<View> _views;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _views = container.Children;

            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(label1, new Rectangle(0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2));
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(label1, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
            label1.SetValue(AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTreeProperty, true);

            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(box2, new Rectangle(0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2));
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(box2, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);

            box2.SetValue(AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTreeProperty, true);
            AutomationProperties.SetName(box2, "Red box");

            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(label3, new Rectangle(0.9, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2));
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(label3, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
            label3.SetValue(AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTreeProperty, true);

            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(buttonChange, new Rectangle(0.5, 0.7, 0.5, 0.2));
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(buttonChange, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);

            _views.ForEach(v => Debug.WriteLine($"Indici: {v.TabIndex}"));

        }

        public void changeFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Cambio focus order");
            //HERE I WOULD LIKE TO DO SOMETHING TO CHANGE THE ACCESSIBILITY ORDER
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i wonder if it is because it doesn't have a label so it gets omitted until everything else is shown. I don't know Xamarin but I would guess the item does not have an accessible name?

Comment: I don't think so because actually with `AutomationProperties.SetName(box2, "Red box");` I set an accessible name to it

Comment: Is `BoxView` actually a, item you can interact with? Sorry I can't help more due to lack of knowledge but this smells to me like the tab order is being ignored because a `BoxView` is not an interactive element so it is being ignored in the tab order until last, I presume if you change it to a button and change the order in the page (but keep the `TabIndex`) it would tab in the correct order?

Comment: Yes if I use a `Button` it works fine, but when I do `box2.SetValue(AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTreeProperty, true);` it should set that `BoxView` as an item I can interact with, but it remain as the last item

Comment: From what I have read there is something 'funky' about `TabIndex` out of the box and some people suggest manually managing focus, but unfortunately I do not know enough to offer any other help than that.

Comment: Found this as well if it is relevant https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7568

Comment: They are recommending to use the new component came as part of the Xamarin Community Toolkit now. SemanticOrderView. More details available at the following link: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/1087